# Adherence to custom-captcha theme requirements

Tags: human-readable

So I'm themeing a custom captcha, and I want to of course adhere to the requirements, which are

```
While theming does give you many options, you need to follow some user interface     consistency rules:

You must state that you are using reCAPTCHA near the CAPTCHA widget.
You must provide a visible button that calls the reload function.
You must provide a way for visually impaired users to access an audio CAPTCHA.
You must provide alt text for any images that you use as buttons in the reCAPTCHA widget.

src: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/customization
```

The first three aren't that hard, but the fourth is a bit tricky - I'm not using actual images, however I am using [fontello glyphs](http://www.fontello.com). I understand that the alt text is in case the image doesn't load, but is it also what's read via text to speech applications for the visually impaired? If so, would it be a good idea to set the alt text on these glyphs as well?

Thank you,
Sidney